# What term describes how certain is a name or a phrase for a search engine?

Tags: seo, keywords, search

I'm pretty sure there is a fancy word that means "searchable" in a context of web search. I will try explain be examples.

"Stack exchange" is a very searchable name, since the first link from google leads to what we want. "Image watch" is searchable for web search, first link leads to the corresponding Visual Studio plugin. But it is not searchable for images search, since all images found by "image watch" phrase actually shows watches of all sorts.

The name of my project on GitHub called "TextGenerator" is not searchable, since there are lots of text generators available on the web. The name of my another project called "Native Viewer" is moderately searchable, since first links lead to LexisNexis legal company, but 5th link leads to the project page on SourceForge.

I hope you got the idea. So, what special term is available instead of this "searchable" thing?

Comment: It's referred to as [brand building](https://moz.com/blog/using-modern-seo-to-build-brand-authority) in the SEO world. This applies to both dictionary and non-dictionary words and phrases. Branding works by having communities, users and media outlets talk about your content, products or services which in turn increases your rankings. Even mentioning the word `TextGenerator` on here, is building your brand, and [Google rewards for mentions](https://datify.co.uk/seo-ranking-factors-do-brand-mentions-matter/)... even if there is no link present on the page.

Comment: The fact your not ranked very high for TextGenerator would be because you need better branding of your product, other people may refer this to keyword link building, but the proper term is branding since Google rewards for mentions, links and other positive signals which extends passed the oldschool keyword algorithms that used link signals (this is however, still ***apart*** of a much larger process).

Comment: Ok, I see your point, thanks. But mentioning is not the only factor. Another factor is uniqueness. E.g. I used to work in a company named Octonus. It is quite small and it is not mentioned a lot, but there is simply _no other entity named Octonus_, this name is unique, and there is no competition for the ranking here. However, with TextGenerator there will always be competition, since the name is very common. I'm looking for a term that represents this "uniqueness".

Comment: Simply having less competition is called... `low competition search keywords`. Your not going to find a word that describes what your looking for, its described in a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Simon's comments.   You are looking for a name that is ***brandable***.

To be brandable, a name should be:

- Unique -- no competition in search engines
- Available -- can register domain name
- Simple -- short, easy to remember
- Different -- stand out from the names of similar products and competitors
- Positive -- the name should evoke positive connotations (strength, speed, ease of use -- something your product has).  Avoid brand names that sound too close to something negative.  (I don't know how anybody ever got away with naming a dog breed the *poo*dle.)

A brand name doesn't have to be descriptive.   It is often better if it is not.   A descriptive name limits customer curiosity.   It may also prevent you from adding features or expanding in ways that don't fit the name.

When you are creating products, it is often good to pair your existing company brand with a descriptive name for the product the way that Google does: Google *docs*, Google *fi*, Google *books*, etc.   That way users don't have to remember so much, only your single brand.  It helps get users to use multiple products from the same company.

Comment: This is not the word I expected to hear, but the answer is pretty close to my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Leave it and don't think about it, it is search engine job.**

There are thousand of webpages talking and using same words for webpages, but Google can't display it on same position.

Let's take one example, I have made site which is brand new let's say it is examplo.com (p.s. Just assume ) so, whenever any people search examplo.com, then google will return example.com site not examplo.com, because may be user have mistypes the words, also Google does not have more data about it.

Now after few months, I was member of many communities like this, and added my site "examplo.com" in description/about section. Some communities have allowed dofollow links and some are not. Both help me to get more readers and natural links.

I have also added my site on search console, where I see how many guys link to me. I have write some great articles, which is displayed in some big newsletter site and people enjoy it, and link to me naturally as a reference.

**Now Google have some data about my site, they understand about examplo.com, they understand this website is exist, and we should return this site first, because it is now most relevant to user query.**

I know my example will look weird but it is the simplest way to describe relevancy.

People link those webpages with that kind of anchor test, and anchor text play a major role in serp. For example just search on Google "Click Here" and you will see adobe page with first position, because many of people use click here anchor text to download adoble plugin. So, It's all about the relevancy, and how people link to other webpages.

Google also use other signal about whether user find it relevant or not, for example, I search some query and click on first link and did not found that information useful, then I click back, and click on second link, and found it useful, so that's kind UX google always looking to it.

Comment: Thank you for elaborated answer, but it does not address my question.